# Bash regexp to find part of string

Tags: linux, bash

I have a string like `setSuperValue('sdfsdfd')` and I need to get the `'sdfsdfd'` value from this line. What is way to do this?

First I find line by `setSuperValue` and then get only string with my target content - `setSuperValue('sdfsdfd')`. How do I build a regexp to get `sdfsdfd` from this line?

Comment: Are you doing this in `bash` or some other language? What's the context here? Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: What have you tried that isn't working? Check out [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) for a place to play with regex before you code it.

Answer (score 2):

This should help you

```
grep setSuperValue myfile.txt | grep -o "'. *'"  | tr -d "'"
```

The `grep -o` will return all text that start with a single ' and ends with another ', including both quotes. Then use `tr` to get rid of the quotes.

You could also use `cut`:

```
 grep setSuperValue myfile.txt | cut -d"'" -f2
```

Or `awk`:

```
 grep setSuperValue myfile.txt | awk -F "'" '{print $2}'
```

This will split the line where the single quotes are and return the second value, that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, to locate a string in multiple lines of data, **external utilities will be much faster than looping over lines in Bash.**

In your specific case, a single `sed` command will do what you want:

```
sed -n -r "s/^.*setSuperValue\('([^']+)'\).*$/\1/p" file
```

- Extended (`-r`) regular expression `^.*setSuperValue\('([^']+)'\).*$` matches any line containing `setSuperValue('...')` as a whole, captures whatever `...` is in capture group `\1`, replaces the input line with that, and prints `p` the result.

  - Due to option `-n`, nothing else is printed.
  - Move the opening and closing `'` inside `(...)` to include them in the captured value.

Note: If the input file contains *multiple* `setSuperValue('...')` lines, the command will print *every* match; either way, the command will *process all lines*.
*To only print the 1st match and stop processing immediately after*, modify the command as follows:

```
sed -n -r "/^.*setSuperValue\('([^']+)'\).*$/ {s//\1/;p;q}" file
```

- `/.../` only *matches* lines containing `setSuperValue('...')`, causing the following `{...}` to be executed only for matching lines.

  - `s//` - i.e., not specifying a regex - implicitly performs substitution based on the same regex that matched the line at hand; `p` prints the result, and `q` quits processing altogether, meaning that processing stops once the fist match was found.

---

If you have already located a line of interest through other methods and are looking for a **pure Bash method of extracting a substring based on a regex, use [`=~`, Bash's regex-matching operator](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs)**, which supports *extended* regular expressions and capture groups through the special `${BASH_REMATCH[@]}` array variable:

```
$ sampleLine="... setSuperValue('sdfsdfd') ..."
$ [[ $sampleLine =~ "setSuperValue('"([^\']+)"')" ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
sdfsdfd
```

Note the careful quoting of the parts of the regex that should be taken *literally*, and how `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}` refers to the first (and only) captured group.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the value from the line, using *parameter expansion/substring removal* without relying on any external tools:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line; do
    value=$(expr "$line" : ".*setSuperValue('\(.*\)')")
    if [ "x$value" != "x" ]; then
        printf "value : %s\n" "$value"
    fi
done <"$1"
```

**Test Input**

```
$ cat dat/supervalue.txt
setSuperValue('sdfsdfd')
something else
setSuperValue('sdfsdfd')
something else
setSuperValue('sdfsdfd')
something else
```

**Example Output**

```
$  bash parsevalue.sh dat/supervalue.txt
value : sdfsdfd
value : sdfsdfd
value : sdfsdfd
```

Comment: Well, `expr` _is_ an external tool, but you could use Bash's built-in `=~` operator instead (which has the added advantage of supporting _extended_ regular expressions).
That said, looping in Bash is generally not the right choice for performance reasons.

Comment: Aside from that, you seem to be using `expr` incorrectly: `expr` with the `:` operator takes a basic regular expression implicitly anchored to the start of the line, whereas you seem to be using a glob-style _pattern_, which, while it happens to be a valid regex in this case, will only do what you want if input lines _start_ with `setSuperValue`.
`expr` will actually allow you to define and return _one_ capture group, which obviates the need for further parsing: `expr "before setSuperValue('foo') after" : ".*setSuperValue('\(.*\)')"` will return `foo`.

Comment: Thanks. Where it occurs was somewhat unclear and I agree with you explanation. The original setup made use of the length of match returned, but returning the value directly is better.

Comment: Thanks for updating; since you only care about whether `$value` is _empty_, it's simpler and more efficient to use `if [[ -n $value ]]; then` (and generally, if you do need the length, to use `${#value}`). As an aside (not a problem here, because the question is tagged 'linux'): `expr length` is a _GNU_ extension to the [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/expr.html).

Comment: Yes, I thought about how best to do that for a second. My thought was since I removed the bash-builtin substring removal, I would leave it `sh` compatible, which it what drove my choice of length. I also thought about `[ -n $value ]` but that isn't an option because the empty string tests true. I can add a variation that will do the same thing.

Comment: `[-n $value ]` tests true for an empty string, because it is effectively the same as `[ -n ]`, which is an implicit non-emptiness test that tests the string _`-n`_ for non-emptiness, which is obviously always true. Your options are: (a) quote `$value`, which you should always do with `[ ... ]` (as opposed to Bash's `[[ ... ]]`): `[ -n "$value" ]`; (b) omit `-n` to perform the implicit non-emptiness test: `[ "$value" ]`; (c) use `[[ ... ]]`, in which case double-quoting is optional: `[[ -n $value ]]` (`[[ $value ]]`) would work too.

Comment: Hah, now that's the piece of the puzzle I was looking for. Another reminder why double-quotes are always required when using `test`.